# How to improve multiplication efficiency in big integer?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, multiplication, biginteger

This weekend I followed the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication#Details) to implement the basic big integer multiplication. I use the Toom-3 algorithm to implement. But the time spends unexpectedly at the beginning is slower than long multiplication(grade-school multiplication) and gone forever. I hope the program can over the grade-school multiplication within 500 digits, How should I do, please?

I try to optimize, I reserve the vector capacity and remove the supernumerary code. But is not very effective.

And should I use the `vector<long long>` to be my base digits?

The whole source code in [Github](https://github.com/cliffxzx/toom-3-in-biginteger):

```cpp
typedef long long BigIntBase;
typedef vector<BigIntBase> BigIntDigits;

// ceil(numeric_limits<BigIntBase>::digits10 / 2.0) - 1;
static const int digit_base_len = 9;
// b
static const BigIntBase digit_base = 1000000000;

class BigInt {

public:
  BigInt(int digits_capacity = 0, bool nega = false) {
    negative = nega;
    digits.reserve(digits_capacity);
  }

  BigInt(BigIntDigits _digits, bool nega = false) {
    negative = nega;
    digits = _digits;
  }

  BigInt(const span<const BigIntBase> &range, bool nega = false) {
    negative = nega;
    digits = BigIntDigits(range.begin(), range.end());
  }

  BigInt operator+(const BigInt &rhs) {
    if ((*this).negative == rhs.negative)
      return BigInt(plus((*this).digits, rhs.digits), (*this).negative);

    if (greater((*this).digits, rhs.digits))
      return BigInt(minus((*this).digits, rhs.digits), (*this).negative);

    return BigInt(minus(rhs.digits, (*this).digits), rhs.negative);
  }

  BigInt operator-(const BigInt &rhs) { return *this + BigInt(rhs.digits, !rhs.negative); }

  BigInt operator*(const BigInt &rhs) {
    if ((*this).digits.empty() || rhs.digits.empty()) {
      return BigInt();
    } else if ((*this).digits.size() == 1 && rhs.digits.size() == 1) {
      BigIntBase val = (*this).digits[0] * rhs.digits[0];
      return BigInt(val < digit_base ? BigIntDigits{val} : BigIntDigits{val % digit_base, val / digit_base}, (*this).negative ^ rhs.negative);
    } else if ((*this).digits.size() == 1)
      return BigInt(multiply(rhs, (*this).digits[0]).digits, (*this).negative ^ rhs.negative);
    else if (rhs.digits.size() == 1)
      return BigInt(multiply((*this), rhs.digits[0]).digits, (*this).negative ^ rhs.negative);

    return BigInt(toom3(span((*this).digits), span(rhs.digits)), (*this).negative ^ rhs.negative);
  }

  string to_string() {
    if (this->digits.empty())
      return "0";

    stringstream ss;
    if (this->negative)
      ss << "-";

    ss << std::to_string(this->digits.back());
    for (auto it = this->digits.rbegin() + 1; it != this->digits.rend(); ++it)
      ss << setw(digit_base_len) << setfill('0') << std::to_string(*it);

    return ss.str();
  }

  BigInt from_string(string s) {
    digits.clear();
    negative = s[0] == '-';
    for (int pos = max(0, (int)s.size() - digit_base_len); pos >= 0; pos -= digit_base_len)
      digits.push_back(stoll(s.substr(pos, digit_base_len)));

    if (s.size() % digit_base_len)
      digits.push_back(stoll(s.substr(0, s.size() % digit_base_len)));

    return *this;
  }

private:
  bool negative;
  BigIntDigits digits;

  const span<const BigIntBase> toom3_slice_num(const span<const BigIntBase> &num, const int &n, const int &i) {
    int begin = n * i;
    if (begin < num.size()) {
      const span<const BigIntBase> result = num.subspan(begin, min((int)num.size() - begin, i));
      return result;
    }

    return span<const BigIntBase>();
  }

  BigIntDigits toom3(const span<const BigIntBase> &num1, const span<const BigIntBase> &num2) {
    int i = ceil(max(num1.size() / 3.0, num2.size() / 3.0));
    const span<const BigIntBase> m0 = toom3_slice_num(num1, 0, i);
    const span<const BigIntBase> m1 = toom3_slice_num(num1, 1, i);
    const span<const BigIntBase> m2 = toom3_slice_num(num1, 2, i);
    const span<const BigIntBase> n0 = toom3_slice_num(num2, 0, i);
    const span<const BigIntBase> n1 = toom3_slice_num(num2, 1, i);
    const span<const BigIntBase> n2 = toom3_slice_num(num2, 2, i);

    BigInt pt0 = plus(m0, m2);
    BigInt pp0 = m0;
    BigInt pp1 = plus(pt0.digits, m1);
    BigInt pn1 = pt0 - m1;
    BigInt pn2 = multiply(pn1 + m2, 2) - m0;
    BigInt pin = m2;

    BigInt qt0 = plus(n0, n2);
    BigInt qp0 = n0;
    BigInt qp1 = plus(qt0.digits, n1);
    BigInt qn1 = qt0 - n1;
    BigInt qn2 = multiply(qn1 + n2, 2) - n0;
    BigInt qin = n2;

    BigInt rp0 = pp0 * qp0;
    BigInt rp1 = pp1 * qp1;
    BigInt rn1 = pn1 * qn1;
    BigInt rn2 = pn2 * qn2;
    BigInt rin = pin * qin;

    BigInt r0 = rp0;
    BigInt r4 = rin;
    BigInt r3 = divide(rn2 - rp1, 3);
    BigInt r1 = divide(rp1 - rn1, 2);
    BigInt r2 = rn1 - rp0;
    r3 = divide(r2 - r3, 2) + multiply(rin, 2);
    r2 = r2 + r1 - r4;
    r1 = r1 - r3;

    BigIntDigits result = r0.digits;
    if (!r1.digits.empty()) {
      shift_left(r1.digits, i);
      result = plus(result, r1.digits);
    }

    if (!r2.digits.empty()) {
      shift_left(r2.digits, i << 1);
      result = plus(result, r2.digits);
    }

    if (!r3.digits.empty()) {
      shift_left(r3.digits, i * 3);
      result = plus(result, r3.digits);
    }

    if (!r4.digits.empty()) {
      shift_left(r4.digits, i << 2);
      result = plus(result, r4.digits);
    }

    return result;
  }

  BigIntDigits plus(const span<const BigIntBase> &lhs, const span<const BigIntBase> &rhs) {
    if (lhs.empty())
      return BigIntDigits(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());

    if (rhs.empty())
      return BigIntDigits(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());

    int max_length = max(lhs.size(), rhs.size());
    BigIntDigits result;
    result.reserve(max_length + 1);

    for (int w = 0; w < max_length; ++w)
      result.push_back((lhs.size() > w ? lhs[w] : 0) + (rhs.size() > w ? rhs[w] : 0));

    for (int w = 0; w < result.size() - 1; ++w) {
      result[w + 1] += result[w] / digit_base;
      result[w] %= digit_base;
    }

    if (result.back() >= digit_base) {
      result.push_back(result.back() / digit_base);
      result[result.size() - 2] %= digit_base;
    }

    return result;
  }

  BigIntDigits minus(const span<const BigIntBase> &lhs, const span<const BigIntBase> &rhs) {
    if (lhs.empty())
      return BigIntDigits(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());

    if (rhs.empty())
      return BigIntDigits(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());

    BigIntDigits result;
    result.reserve(lhs.size() + 1);

    for (int w = 0; w < lhs.size(); ++w)
      result.push_back((lhs.size() > w ? lhs[w] : 0) - (rhs.size() > w ? rhs[w] : 0));

    for (int w = 0; w < result.size() - 1; ++w)
      if (result[w] < 0) {
        result[w + 1] -= 1;
        result[w] += digit_base;
      }

    while (!result.empty() && !result.back())
      result.pop_back();

    return result;
  }

  void shift_left(BigIntDigits &lhs, const int n) {
    if (!lhs.empty()) {
      BigIntDigits zeros(n, 0);
      lhs.insert(lhs.begin(), zeros.begin(), zeros.end());
    }
  }

  BigInt divide(const BigInt &lhs, const int divisor) {
    BigIntDigits reminder(lhs.digits);
    BigInt result(lhs.digits.capacity(), lhs.negative);

    for (int w = reminder.size() - 1; w >= 0; --w) {
      result.digits.insert(result.digits.begin(), reminder[w] / divisor);
      reminder[w - 1] += (reminder[w] % divisor) * digit_base;
    }

    while (!result.digits.empty() && !result.digits.back())
      result.digits.pop_back();

    return result;
  }

  BigInt multiply(const BigInt &lhs, const int multiplier) {
    BigInt result(lhs.digits, lhs.negative);

    for (int w = 0; w < result.digits.size(); ++w)
      result.digits[w] *= multiplier;

    for (int w = 0; w < result.digits.size(); ++w)
      if (result.digits[w] >= digit_base) {
        if (w + 1 == result.digits.size())
          result.digits.push_back(result.digits[w] / digit_base);
        else
          result.digits[w + 1] += result.digits[w] / digit_base;
        result.digits[w] %= digit_base;
      }

    return result;
  }

  bool greater(const BigIntDigits &lhs, const BigIntDigits &rhs) {
    if (lhs.size() == rhs.size()) {
      int w = lhs.size() - 1;
      while (w >= 0 && lhs[w] == rhs[w])
        --w;

      return w >= 0 && lhs[w] > rhs[w];
    } else
      return lhs.size() > rhs.size();
  }
};
```

| Digits | Grade-school | Toom-3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 4588 | 10003 |
| 50 | 24147 | 109084 |
| 100 | 52165 | 286535 |
| 150 | 92405 | 476275 |
| 200 | 172156 | 1076570 |
| 250 | 219599 | 1135946 |
| 300 | 320939 | 1530747 |
| 350 | 415655 | 1689745 |
| 400 | 498172 | 1937327 |
| 450 | 614467 | 2629886 |
| 500 | 863116 | 3184277 |

Comment: Are you timing a Release or optimized build?

Comment: what is the release build?

Comment: A release build means that you are compiling a version of your application with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Well, since `release_capacity`'s default parameter is 0, this ends up calling `reserve(0)`, which doesn't accomplish much of anything. And in the same constructor, `digits = BigIntDigits();` also does absolutely nothing whatsoever since `digits` is already default-constructed. Not much of a waste, but stlil a waste. And the other constructor does not reserve anything, either. So just a first look at this finds some obvious oversights, so I would expect that it's likely the rest of the algorithms are also missing obvious optimizations.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  You are missing the actual test program you used.

Comment: @drescherjm I use the same environment to compile two algorithm code. Should I give the optimize flag in the compiler? It will lead to a different comparison result?

Comment: Depending on your compiler it might need some flag like `-O3` (at least in release)

Comment: I reserve when in calculate, And by my timing, the construct BigInt(int) just spent 2% in all spent time, the most spent time is constructed BigInt(BigIntDigits), It spent 18% time. But according to your suggestion, I edit my code, thank you.

Comment: @Cliff you must always build with optimizations on to benchmark. Otherwise the code is just useful for debugging

Comment: `BigInt qt0 = BigInt(n0) + BigInt(n2);` makes 3(?) allocations, but you have already changed `plus` to take the `std::span` so you could add an operator+ that takes a span too.

Comment: @Surt oh! I miss it, But after I edit the code, it seems like not a remarkable change.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you do a million allocations in among others `toom3_slice_num`, here you could use a `std::span` (or a std::pair of iterator to the actual part) as the number you give is a const. `toom3` is also allocator hell.

The `multiply` might allocate 1 more time. Count the bits needed or just add 1 to the size.

And the `vector`s should be `pmr` (with appropriate allocator) for nearly lock free allocations.

All this is wasted if not compiled with `-O2` or `-O3`.

Comment: I took some of your advice. I update the code with use span to slice toom3 nums and compile with -O3 flag. It truly improves efficiency. The originally spent time is 5% in total time, now is 1%, thank you.